# Cantilever Beam Deflection under Plane strain

Tags: beam, deflection

I have a university code that calculates the maximum deflection of cantilever beam of length, $L$ subjected to a point load, $P$ on its free end. The software assumes plane strain conditions. I calculated the maximum deflection, $\delta$ manually using the formula, $\delta = PL^3/3EI$. However the results do not match. Can someone help me understand how I would calculate the deflection using plane strain assumption?

Comment: What is a University code? Why not check out a book by Timoshenko - even online.

Comment: It would be useful if you could present what are the dimensions of the cantilever beam, material and the load, and also what are your results and the code results. IMHO this is either a very broad question that needs more focus, or its a resource hunting question which is not suitable for this site.